# Proper way of using npm timepicker Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, npm, timepicker

I am new in installing packages in Laravel. Now, I am trying to implement `timepicker` from https://timepicker.co/. I already installed **npm i jquery-timepicker**.

What is the next thing in doing it? I always get `timepicker` is not a function when running this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({});
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to require that plugin, where you require jQuery to your application.

It has to be something like this.

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
require('timepicker')
```

Comment: I required jQuery in `bootstrap.js` but after placing `require('timepicker');` it says :

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timepicker'`

Comment: The parameter in require function should be timepickers export value. If there is no exportable module, you can always use dist versions. `Include jquery.timepicker.css and jquery.timepicker.min.js in your page.` Which should be something like `require('timepicker/dist/jquery.timepicker.min.js')`